Difference between new message and use reply and erasing everything
Consider the following two scenarios:

I write a new e-mail on my e-mail client, to johndoe@mail.com.
I hit the "reply" button on a totally unrelated e-mail that johndoe@mail.com previously sent me. I erase the subject (including the "Re:" part) and the contents of the e-mail (it contains a copy of johndoe@mail.com's message) so that the message looks brand new and start writing my message.

Assume you are johndoe@mail.com, and I perform one of these scenarii.
Is there some way you (in fact, your e-mail client) could tell which scenario I chose?

I am not sure this is the right SE website for my question, sorry in advance if it's not :(

Email headers contain a variety of information. Individual email client software may or may not be able read/write/understand all the possible headers, so this WILL vary between clients, but the short answer is:
Yes, the email client will know it is a reply even if you change the subject
A couple of the possible headers that client software could use to tell an email is a reply are:

Thread-Topic: This value is different from Subject, but is created when the first reply is created. The original Subject value is written to Thread-Topic, and then the Subject of the reply has the "RE:" bit prefixed.
References: This value stores the Message IDs of the previous replies in the thread. With each new reply, new Message IDs are appended to this value.

What happens to Thread-Topic when you edit the subject, return the email, and the recipient replies themselves? I don't actually know. I didn't test that. It may update to reflect there is now a new Thread Topic, or it may stay as it was.
But, the general rule of thumb is that unless you modify the HEADERS of the email, the receiving client COULD very well know the email is, in fact, a reply.
